# git format-patch without committing

Tags: git, patch

How can I generate the patch between HEAD and the staging area (without committing)?

e.g.

```
echo text > some.file
git add some.file
git format-patch (what-the-sha?)..HEAD
```

Do I have to commit then reset?

Answer (score 9):

```
git diff --cached
```

should do the trick if you just want the patch diff.

If you really want all of the functionality of `format-patch`, though, you really should commit (after all, you want a commit message if you're submitting a patch upstream).